Splitting multiline text before data cleaning.What option for splitting Oracle userform data?
I'm a medical doctor, just starting Python, so excuse me if I misuse some terms.
We use an Oracle Userform for our Electronic Health System.
Blood Pressure data appears in a text field, and can contain up to 650 individual blood pressure measurements.
This is an example of 4 measurements:
 = 01-02-2024 16:05 - A. I AHMED
    128 / 84 
 = 01-02-2024 08:07 - G. I AL KHAIR
    122 / 80 
 = 01-02-2024 00:48 - E. H AL MALKY
    122 / 80 
 = 31-01-2024 00:48 - M. SHIBI
    124 / 

The main issue with this data is that it can't be directly analysed, because it's a string.
Analyses, such as averages or terminal digit preference, requires data to be cleaned, with dates as datetime.date, time as datetime.time, blood pressure as Integer...
It seems that, before cleaning the data, and storing every type of data into a variable (date, time, nurse_name, systolic, diastolic), I can (?) / have to (?) parse and split this multiline data into separate lines.
I tried this:
data = """
= 23-10-2023 01:43 - M. M AL FAKEEH
    119 / 79 
= 03-10-2023 23:49 - H. I ADAM
112 /
= 03-10-2023 23:49 - H. I ADAM
/ 70
= 03-10-2023 16:32 - S. M JEEZ
/ 76
= 03-10-2023 16:32 - S. M JEEZ
120 / 
= 03-10-2023 08:54 - S. I YOUNIS
122 / 81
"""

# Split the data into lines
lines = data.split('\n')

raw_BP_data_odd_lines = []
raw_BP_data_even_lines = []
for i, line in enumerate(lines):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        raw_BP_data_even_lines.append(line)
    else:
        raw_BP_data_odd_lines.append(line)

# Split the data inside raw_BP_data_odd_lines and raw_BP_data_even_lines
odd_lines_split = [line.split() for line in raw_BP_data_odd_lines]

even_lines_split = [line.split() for line in raw_BP_data_even_lines]
     #This split the data in each line into separate words

print("Odd lines:")
#for line in odd_lines_split:
for line in raw_BP_data_odd_lines:
    print(line)  # This means: Print every line in the variable "odd_lines_split"

print("Even lines:")
#for line in even_lines_split:
for line in raw_BP_data_even_lines:
    print(line)

The result contained an unexpected empty line after "Even lines:
Odd lines:
= 23-10-2023 01:43 - M. M AL FAKEEH
= 03-10-2023 23:49 - H. I ADAM
= 03-10-2023 23:49 - H. I ADAM
= 03-10-2023 16:32 - S. M JEEZ
= 03-10-2023 16:32 - S. M JEEZ
= 03-10-2023 08:54 - S. I YOUNIS


Even lines:

    119 / 79
112 /
/ 70
/ 76
120 /
122 / 81

I'm guessing the issue lies in choosing the "\n" delimiter when splitting the lines.
So I decided to try pasting the blood pressure data from the clipboard to a variable, hoping it would solve the issue of the unexpected space. But the output was worse (nothing at all was printed):
import pyperclip

# Paste data from the clipboard into a variable
clipboard_data = pyperclip.paste()

# Check if clipboard data is empty
if not clipboard_data:
    print("No data found in the clipboard.")
else:
    # Split the data into lines
    lines = clipboard_data.split('\n')

I read, on this forum, about using os.linesep
import os
import pyperclip
text=pyperclip.paste()     
                             #paste will paste a big string of text in 'text' string

# Separate lines and add stars
lines = text.split(os.linesep)

Is os.linesep my best option to avoid the unwanted empty line?
Accessory question:
Am I on the right track in order to clean the blood pressure data and separate it into the 4 different data types it contains?

You can use a regular expression and iterate over matches to the regular expression:
import re
from datetime import datetime

data = """
= 23-10-2023 01:43 - M. M AL FAKEEH
    119 / 79 
= 03-10-2023 23:49 - H. I ADAM
112 /
= 03-10-2023 23:49 - H. I ADAM
/ 70
= 03-10-2023 16:32 - S. M JEEZ
/ 76
= 03-10-2023 16:32 - S. M JEEZ
120 / 
= 03-10-2023 08:54 - S. I YOUNIS
122 / 81
"""

pattern = re.compile(
    "(?<=\n)=\s+"
    + "(?P<date>(?:[012]\d|3[01])-(?:0\d|1[012])-\d{4}\s+[0-5]\d:[0-5]\d)"
    + "\s*-\s*"
    + "(?P<name>.*?)"
    + "\n\s*"
    + "(?P<systolic>\d*)"
    + "\s*/\s*"
    + "(?P<diastolic>\d*)"
    + "\s*(?=\n)"
)

for match in pattern.finditer(data):
    name = match.group("name")
    dt = datetime.strptime(match.group("date"), "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M")
    systolic = int(match.group("systolic")) if match.group("systolic") != "" else None
    diastolic = int(match.group("diastolic")) if match.group("diastolic") != "" else None
    print(f"{name} - {dt}: {systolic}/{diastolic}")

Which outputs:
M. M AL FAKEEH - 2023-10-23 01:43:00: 119/79
H. I ADAM - 2023-10-03 23:49:00: 112/None
H. I ADAM - 2023-10-03 23:49:00: None/70
S. M JEEZ - 2023-10-03 16:32:00: None/76
S. M JEEZ - 2023-10-03 16:32:00: 120/None
S. I YOUNIS - 2023-10-03 08:54:00: 122/81

If you want to generate a data structure to hold the data then you can use:
from __future__ import annotations

from datetime import datetime
from re import compile, Pattern
from typing import ClassVar, List, Optional

data = """
= 23-10-2023 01:43 - M. M AL FAKEEH
    119 / 79 
= 03-10-2023 23:49 - H. I ADAM
112 /
= 03-10-2023 23:49 - H. I ADAM
/ 70
= 03-10-2023 16:32 - S. M JEEZ
/ 76
= 03-10-2023 16:32 - S. M JEEZ
120 / 
= 03-10-2023 08:54 - S. I YOUNIS
122 / 81
"""

class BloodPressureData:
    pattern: ClassVar[Pattern] = compile(
        "(?<=\n)=\s*"
        + "(?P<date>(?:[012]\d|3[01])-(?:0\d|1[012])-\d{4}\s+[0-5]\d:[0-5]\d)"
        + "\s*-\s*"
        + "(?P<name>.*?)"
        + "\n\s*"
        + "(?P<systolic>\d*)"
        + "\s*/\s*"
        + "(?P<diastolic>\d*)"
        + "\s*(?=\n)"
    )

    name: str
    datetime: datetime
    systolic: Optional[int]
    diastolic: Optional[int]
    
    def __init__(
        self,
        name: str,
        datetime: datetime,
        systolic: Optional[int],
        diastolic: Optional[int],
    ) -> None:
        self.name = name
        self.datetime = datetime
        self.systolic = systolic
        self.diastolic = diastolic
    
    @staticmethod
    def parse(data: str) -> List[BloodPressureData]:
        values: List[BloodPressureData] = []
        for match in BloodPressureData.pattern.finditer(data):
            systolic = match.group("systolic")
            diastolic = match.group("diastolic")
            values.append(
                BloodPressureData(
                    name=match.group("name"),
                    datetime=datetime.strptime(match.group("date"), "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M"),
                    systolic=int(systolic) if systolic != "" else None,
                    diastolic=int(diastolic) if diastolic != "" else None,
                )
            )
        return values
        
    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f"{self.name} - {self.datetime}: {self.systolic}/{self.diastolic}"


for value in BloodPressureData.parse(data):
    print(value)

The output is identical but it may be more useful in the future to have the data in a class.

Using pyperclip:
from __future__ import annotations

import pyperclip

from datetime import datetime
from re import compile, Pattern
from typing import ClassVar, List, Optional

class BloodPressureData:
    pattern: ClassVar[Pattern] = compile(
        "(?<=\n)=\s*"
        + "(?P<date>(?:[012]\d|3[01])-(?:0\d|1[012])-\d{4}\s+[0-5]\d:[0-5]\d)"
        + "\s*-\s*"
        + "(?P<name>.*?)"
        + "\n\s*"
        + "(?P<systolic>\d*)"
        + "\s*/\s*"
        + "(?P<diastolic>\d*)"
        + "\s*(?=\n)"
    )

    name: str
    datetime: datetime
    systolic: Optional[int]
    diastolic: Optional[int]
    
    def __init__(
        self,
        name: str,
        datetime: datetime,
        systolic: Optional[int],
        diastolic: Optional[int],
    ) -> None:
        self.name = name
        self.datetime = datetime
        self.systolic = systolic
        self.diastolic = diastolic
    
    @staticmethod
    def parse(data: str) -> List[BloodPressureData]:
        values: List[BloodPressureData] = []
        for match in BloodPressureData.pattern.finditer(data):
            systolic = match.group("systolic")
            diastolic = match.group("diastolic")
            values.append(
                BloodPressureData(
                    name=match.group("name"),
                    datetime=datetime.strptime(match.group("date"), "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M"),
                    systolic=int(systolic) if systolic != "" else None,
                    diastolic=int(diastolic) if diastolic != "" else None,
                )
            )
        return values
        
    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f"{self.name} - {self.datetime}: {self.systolic}/{self.diastolic}"

data = pyperclip.paste()

if not data:
    print("No data found in the clipboard.")
else:
    for value in BloodPressureData.parse(data):
        print(value)



When I use pyperclip to store data before processing it with your script, the script seems to block. When I press enter again, it only outputs error messages, without printing any blood pressure data. I mean, it's not about future import annotations being written in a wrong place.

@YassineJones The code added at the bottom of the answer works for me (after I installed pyperclip and its dependencies).

Unfortunately, it did not work for me. I had copied the same kind of data from a .txt file. The .txt file contained the blood pressure data that I had copied from the Oracle Userform text output we use at work. I guess the issue is way above my level: I frankly do not even know what question to ask to find a solution... (How to remove all unexpected characters from string python??? What are the best practices for handling and cleaning data copied from external sources before processing it in Python?)

@YassineJones Copy the data from the question into the clipboard, does it run? Yes, good, move onto more testing. Copy the data from one of your text files into the clipboard, does it run? Yes, good. No, copy half the file into the clipboard and retest. Keep repeating with halves, quarters, eighths, etc until you find a single pair of lines that doesn't work. Work out what is wrong with that pair of line (or else post another question on SO asking about it).

I'll copy data directly from the Oracle Userform then see if your script works. I'm starting to experience the impact of the source from which I take my data; there might be big differences between Oracle's text outputbwindow, and .txt files... @MT0 In any case, thanks for your answer and comments.

Step 1: Odd lines & Even lines in 2 separate variables without unwanted empty line:
os.linesep seems to be a valid option (best option or not, I don't know):
1. it did separate data **stored in a variable** into lines;

2. it did remove the **unwanted extra line** for even lines.

This is the initial part of the code:
import pyperclip
import os

# Paste data from the clipboard into a variable
clipboard_data = pyperclip.paste()

# Split the data into lines
lines = clipboard_data.split(os.linesep)

''' Store odd lines (line 1, 3, 5...) in raw_BP_data_odd_lines
      and even lines (line 2, 4, 6, 8...) in raw_BP_data_even_lines'''
raw_BP_data_odd_lines = []
raw_BP_data_even_lines = []
for i, line in enumerate(lines):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        raw_BP_data_even_lines.append(line)
    else:
        raw_BP_data_odd_lines.append(line)

# Split the data inside raw_BP_data_odd_lines and raw_BP_data_even_lines
odd_lines_split = [line.split() for line in raw_BP_data_odd_lines]
even_lines_split = [line.split() for line in raw_BP_data_even_lines]

This is the output:
Odd lines:
    128 / 84
    122 / 80
    122 / 80
    122 / 83
    122 / 83
    119 / 79
112 /
 / 70
Even lines:
 = 01-02-2024 16:05 - A. I AHMED
 = 01-02-2024 08:07 - G. I AL KHAIR
 = 01-02-2024 00:48 - E. H AL MALKY
 = 24-10-2023 00:42 - M. M ALHARTHI
 = 23-10-2023 07:48 - S. S AL OTABI
 = 23-10-2023 01:43 - M. M AL FAKEEH
 = 03-10-2023 23:49 - H. I ADAM
 = 03-10-2023 23:49 - H. I ADAM

As to whether I'm "on the right track in order to clean the blood pressure data and separate it into the 4 different data types it contains", I'll continue trying till I find a solution. Then I'll answer here.
Step 2: Duplicating variables:
[even_lines_split] becomes:
1. BPdata_dates
2. BPdata_times
3. BPdata_names
[odd_lines_split] becomes:
1. BPdata_systolic
2. BPdata_diastolic
Step 3: Making replace operations on the 5 variables:
Step 4: Finding a way to send the data to a PostgreSQL database
Step 5: Trying to understand and use MT0's much more elegant approach
Test script, using this pattern
pattern: ClassVar[Pattern] = compile(
    "^\s*=\s*"
    + "(?P<date>(?:[012]\d|3[01])-(?:0\d|1[012])-\d{4}\s+[0-5]\d:[0-5]\d)"
    + "\s*-\s*"
    + "(?P<name>.*?)"
    + "\n\s*"
    + "(?P<systolic>\d*)"
    + "\s*/\s*"
    + "(?P<diastolic>\d*)"
    + "\s*(?=\n)"
)


Better regular expression:
This script was generated by GPT-4o, after I exposed my problem and presented MT0's script:
from __future__ import annotations

from datetime import datetime
from re import compile, Pattern, MULTILINE
from typing import ClassVar, List, Optional
import pyperclip

# Paste data from the clipboard into a variable
data = pyperclip.paste()

class BloodPressureData:
    pattern: ClassVar[Pattern] = compile(
        r"^\s*=\s*"
        r"(?P<date>(?:[012]\d|3[01])-(?:0\d|1[012])-\d{4}\s+[0-5]\d:[0-5]\d)"
        r"\s*-\s*"
        r"(?P<name>[^\n]+)"
        r"\s*\n\s*"
        r"(?P<systolic>\d*)"
        r"\s*/\s*"
        r"(?P<diastolic>\d*)"
        r"\s*(?=\n|$)",
        MULTILINE
    )

    name: str
    datetime: datetime
    systolic: Optional[int]
    diastolic: Optional[int]
    
    def __init__(
        self,
        name: str,
        datetime: datetime,
        systolic: Optional[int],
        diastolic: Optional[int],
    ) -> None:
        self.name = name
        self.datetime = datetime
        self.systolic = systolic
        self.diastolic = diastolic
    
    @staticmethod
    def parse(data: str) -> List[BloodPressureData]:
        values: List[BloodPressureData] = []
        for match in BloodPressureData.pattern.finditer(data):
            systolic = match.group("systolic")
            diastolic = match.group("diastolic")
            values.append(
                BloodPressureData(
                    name=match.group("name").strip(),
                    datetime=datetime.strptime(match.group("date"), "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M"),
                    systolic=int(systolic) if systolic else None,
                    diastolic=int(diastolic) if diastolic else None,
                )
            )
        return values
        
    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f"{self.name} - {self.datetime}: {self.systolic}/{self.diastolic}"

for value in BloodPressureData.parse(data):
    print(value)

It uses:
-re.compile, apparently for greater parsing efficiency;
-re.multiline, which seems to have solved a warnings issue when running MT0's script (if I'm not wrong, this topic is raised in Python documentation here DeprecationWarning).
ANSWER TO QUESTIONS:

Main question: No. os.linesep does not seem to be the best option to avoid the unwanted empty line. Using regular expressions seems better.
Accessory question: No. I don't think I was on the right track for parsing the blood pressure data.
Here too, regular expressions seem better.

